# reseting filter if "All" is selected Vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, select, filter

I have this array of objects:

```
obj=
[{name: 'joe', job: 'teacher', city: 'miami'},
{name: 'bill', job: 'police', city: 'yorkshire'},
{name: 'sarah', job: 'driver', city: 'michigan'}]
```

And I have a dropdown menu with options like this:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option>blue</option>
  <option>green</option>
  <option>black</option>
  <option>all</option>
</select>
```

and then if one of them is selected I associate them with an object from the array:

```
if (selected === "blue") {
  optionSelected = 'joe'
} else if (selected === "green") {
  optionSelected = 'bill'
} else if (selected === "black") {
  optionSelected = 'sarah'
} else if (selected === "all") {
  // what should go here?
}
```

And I filter through it like this:

```
obj = obj.filter(object => object.name === optionSelected)
```

So now if I select `blue` my `obj` becomes `{name: 'bill', job: 'police', city: 'yorkshire'}` and so on and it is good. However I don't know how to filter for `all`. So when it is selected `obj` resets to contain all of the values like:

```
obj=
[{name: 'joe', job: 'teacher', city: 'miami'},
{name: 'bill', job: 'police', city: 'yorkshire'},
{name: 'sarah', job: 'driver', city: 'michigan'}]
```

How can I do this?

*PLEASE NOTE*:
The architecture of code is setup this way and I cannot change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with an object that maps colours to names so you can avoid all that `if..else if` stuff

```js
const colorNameMap = {
  blue: 'joe',
  green: 'bill',
  black: 'sarah',
  all: false // totally optional since undefined is falsy
}
```

Then you simply check if the selected colour matches something in the map. If it doesn't, just return the entire `obj`

```js
const name = colorNameMap[this.selected]
const filtered = name ? obj.filter(o => o.name === name) : obj
```